# MoveFocus() inside UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm building a custom `DatePicker` in WPF using a `UserControl`. My control inside it has 3 TextBoxes that take care of indicating day month and year based on the cultureInfo.
I am trying to move the focus from one textbox to another to simplify data entry but I always have the same problem, the focus moves but always ends up at the first of the 3 textboxes inside the control.
Here is the code of TextChanged event that is one for all three texboxes:

```
    private void _DateTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        EvolutionTextbox textBox = sender as EvolutionTextbox;
        string tagText = textBox.TagText.ToString();
        int value;
        bool emptyText = false;
        bool isNumber = Int32.TryParse(textBox.InputText, out value);

        if (textBox.InputText == "") {
            emptyText = true;
        }

        _UnregisterEvents();
        int year = 2024; // default value for year
        int month = 1; // default value for month
        int day = 1; // default value for day

        // get current input from textboxes
        if (_YearTextBox.InputText != "" && _YearTextBox.InputText.Count() == 4) {
            year = Int32.Parse(_YearTextBox.InputText);
        }
        if (_MonthTextBox.InputText != "" && Int32.Parse(_MonthTextBox.InputText) < 12 && Int32.Parse(_MonthTextBox.InputText) > 0) {
            month = Int32.Parse(_MonthTextBox.InputText);
        }
        if (_DayTextBox.InputText != "") {
            day = Int32.Parse(_DayTextBox.InputText);
        }

        int maxDay = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);

        switch (tagText) {
            case "d": // Day
                if (value <= 0 || value > maxDay) {
                    ((EvolutionTextbox)sender).InputText = maxDay.ToString();
                }
                break;
            case "M": // Month
                if (value <= 0 || value > 12) {
                    ((EvolutionTextbox)sender).InputText = "12";
                }
                else if (value <= 12) {
                    maxDay = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, value);
                    if (day > maxDay) {
                        _DayTextBox.InputText = maxDay.ToString();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "yyyy": // Year
                if (value <= 0 || value > 9999) {
                    ((EvolutionTextbox)sender).InputText = "9999";
                }
                else if (value > 0) {
                    maxDay = DateTime.DaysInMonth(value, month);
                    if (day > maxDay) {
                        _DayTextBox.InputText = maxDay.ToString();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

        // If empty set empty string
        if (emptyText) {
            ((EvolutionTextbox)sender).InputText = "";
        }

        _RegisterEvents();

        //jump between textboxes

        if ((tagText == "d" || tagText == "M") && textBox.InputText.Length == 2) {
            TraversalRequest req = new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
            MoveFocus(req);
        }
        else if (tagText == "yyyy" && textBox.InputText.Length == 4) {
            TraversalRequest req = new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
            MoveFocus(req);
        }


            
    }
```

I also tried putting `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Contained"` and also `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"` but they did not have the desired effect. I also tried setting the `TabIndex` of the various controls by putting TabIndex = 1,2,3 for the respective controls.
I do not understand what may be missing or what I am doing wrong!

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are observing is correct: you are *always* calling `FrameworkElement.MoveFocus` on the parent `UserControl` to move the focus to the next element. And the next element in the hierarchy is the first `TextBox`. Unless you move the elements inside the child element tree the next element relative to the `MoveFocus` caller will never change.

You have to call `MoveFocus` on the currently focused element to continue focus traversal.

Assuming that you use the same `_DateTextBox_TextChanged` event handler for all `TextBox.TextChanged` events of the participating `TextBox` elements then you must change the focus navigation part as follows:

```cs
private void _DateTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var textBox = (EvolutionTextbox)sender;
  string tagText = textBox.TagText.ToString();

  ...

  // Move focus to next TextBox 

  bool isInputDayOrMonth = tagText == "d" || tagText == "M";
  int expectedInputLength = isInputDayOrMonth ? 2 : 4;
  if (textBox.InputText.Length == expectedInputLength) 
  {
    TraversalRequest req = new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next);
    //MoveFocus(req);

    // Move from the currently focused element (TextBox) to the next element
    textBox.MoveFocus(req);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I tried your code but still did not get the desired effect. I am thinking that there is a problem on my side regarding the focus of the elements inside the custom control

Comment: It would be helpful if you could update your question and post the XAML of the UserControl and all the required code (latest version that integrates the suggested fix) in order to replicate the behavior. This way I can review your code properly.

Comment: Thanks but I solved in another way. Instead of using MoveFocus() I make a switch case and force the focus to the right textbox.

Comment: That's not  nice. Aren't the TextBoxes next to each other or are there other elements between them?